# how to import data into system versioned table in sql server?

Tags: sql-server

Import data from Dev to QA for a system versioned table. But is failing. Table is already created in QA. But it is failing due to system versioned start date and End Date.

I used SSMS  import option.

It is showing an index out of bound error.

[image]

Comment: I see you've enabled Identity Insert, are you importing the actual Identity Column? If not, deselect it and try again?

Comment: That I have tried. I doubt import wizard trying to insert Start date and End Date.

Comment: Have you considered doing it via a script?

Comment: That needs a linked server right?. I do not have it.

Comment: If it's two separate instances or 2 separate servers, yes, it would require a Linked Server - to setup a linked server is very easy. You can do so using this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/linked-servers/create-linked-servers-sql-server-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017), as a guide if need be.